# Count unverified firebase users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to see how many firebase-authenticated users have not verified their email yet? I would have guessed something like that to be available on the firebase console, but I do not find anything as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no counter of unverified users in the Firebase Console, nor is there a public API to get that count.

The easiest way I can think of is [exporting the list of users with the `auth:export` command in the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport) and then counting them there.